# Reporting issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on an application which needs to produce reports containing the data of a datagrid as it is (including multiple dynamic filters). My filtering currently gets a result set from an SQL query which causes the following problem: I cannot send multiple where filters to either SSRS or Crystal reports because it won't let me bind the fields to the dynamically generated query.

This is my question: Is there any way to create reports with an unlimited amount of conditions in the where statement or to create a stored procedure with a dynamic where clause so that I can use it with either CR or SSRS? And if not, is there any reporting engine that would allow me to concatenate that filter in the where clause?

Note: I'm using C# 4.0 along with SQL Server 2008 Express (w/SSRS installed) and the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 library by SAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging in Crystal Reports, I found out that with commands and parameters it is possible to concatenate a part of a where statement into the query, which somewhat solves my problem. This isn't how reporting should be done, so I'll try to find a cleaner way to do this. SSRS just does not support this, in a Stored Procedure case, you would have to make the whole query a string that you execute, and then query from that Stored Procedure result as if it was a table, which frankly isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick to add filters when they are defined is to add the following code in your where clause :

```
where (@param is null or @param = field)
```

So, when the `@param` is not defined (null), then the filter is not applied. You can build a longer where clause, like :

```
where (@param1 is null or @param1 = field1)
  and (@param2 is null or @param2 = field2)
  and (@param3 is null or @param3 = field3)
  and (@param4 is null or @param4 = field4)
  ...
```

Comment: This won't work because the number of parameters isn't defined. One user can filter only on one field while another one could very well use 5+ filters. I don't think having a for loop to generate this for every parameter in the report would be very clean.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of parameters isn't defined"? It has to be defined in the report or the user won't be able to select which filter to apply.

Comment: That's what I mean, the user is the one defining the filter and I need to filter the report with the filters that the user has at that moment, something like a wysiwyg report from a filtered datagrid. Is such a thing possible in Crystal Reports or SSRS?

Comment: Now I understand. Your question was about the WHERE statement, so I assumed you already had your parameters setup in SSRS - which you havn't. You are looking for a way to add dynamic filters in the report itself. Unfortunately, in SSRS, you have to define the report parameters so the user can filter on them.